# Google Form Submit Event : TypeError: Cannot call method "getRow" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

[image]

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('About', 'showAbout')
  .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function testFormSubmit (event) {
  try {

    //{"response":{},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":2146837001}
    Logger.log( JSON.stringify(event) ); 

    var responce = event.response;
    Logger.log("responce.getId(): -------------");
    Logger.log( responce.getId() );

    Logger.log("responce.getEditResponseUrl(): ----------------");
    Logger.log( responce.getEditResponseUrl() );

    var ss = event.source; //Spreadsheet

    //Logger.log( event.range.getA1Notation() );
    Logger.log("event.range.getRow(): ----------------");
    Logger.log( event.range.getRow() );
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

I have the error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRow" of undefined

I have read [Documentation (triggers/events)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) and  [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)  and [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
but I still don't understand what I need to do in order to get ***event.range.getRow()*** (everything else works fine)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of triggers driven by form submission: [Sheets trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) (which you create using Sheets script editor) and [Forms trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) (created using Forms script editor). Their event objects are different. The Sheets trigger has `range` property, the Forms trigger does not. You are using a Forms trigger.

If you need to know in which row the entries are logged, use the Sheets trigger (Note: it won't have `response` property). The documentation you link to has all this information.

Comment: Ah so... Thank you for explanation. Could you say - is it possible to use both kind of triggers simultaneously?
I need: 
var timestamp =  formResponse.getTimestamp();
var responseUniqueId = event.response.getId();
and rowNumber as well

Comment: You can use both triggers, but they will fire independently. You'll need two functions, one processing the Sheets trigger and another the Forms trigger. There is no process that will give you both at the same time, or match one event object to the other. Sheets trigger knows nothing about the form; it sees the values and knows where they are in the spreadsheet. Forms trigger knows nothing about the spreadsheet.

Comment: Forms trigger should know something about the spreadsheet: row, or Sheets trigger should know response id... in other case I don't understand how was implemented editting after submit?